# Insertion List Linked in Java (Debug)

Tags: java, linked-list, jgrasp

I am trying to build a linked list as is shown below:

```
**list-> [C] - [B] - [A] -> NULL**
```

Here is my main:

```
import java.util.*; 

class LinkedListF
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {    
        Node aNode = new Node ("A", null);
        Node bNode = new Node ("B", aNode);
        Node list = new Node ("C",bNode);  

        DynamicList dynamicList = new DynamicList();   
        dynamicList.insertFirst("A");
        dynamicList.insertFirst("C");
        dynamicList.insertAfter(list, "B");
        //the line above is where I am struggling with.

        System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getInfo());
        System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getNext().getInfo());
        System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getNext().getNext().getInfo());
    }
}
```

The problem I am having now, as I mark in the codes, is when the code "`dynamicList.insertAfter(list, "B")`" runs, it does not insert "B" after the Node "list" in the dynamicList that I construct.  I am very confused about what is happening here.

My output looks like this:

```
----jGRASP exec: java LinkedListF

C
A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedListF.main(LinkedListF.java:27)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

The line 27 is my third System.out.print statement.

Below is the insertAfter method in my DynamicList class:

```
public void insertAfter(Node p, String x)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("VOID INSERTION.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Node q = new Node (x, p.getNext());
    p.setNext(q);
}
```

Below is the Node class that I use to construct each node:

```
class Node
{
    private String data;
    private Node next;

    public Node (String data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    String getInfo()
    {
        return data;
    }

    Node getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    void setInfo(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException at LinkedListF.main(LinkedListF.java:27)". What is on line 27 ?

Comment: @Thilo *"The line 27 is my third System.out.print statement."*

Comment: You do understand that `list` is never added to `dynamicList`, right?

Comment: There is a difference between `list` and the node created by `insertFirst("C")`

Comment: @azurefrog Yeah, it's a bit strange way to do it, the method could be in fact static, but as I see it, it is added to `dynamicList` because he passes the node `list` (which is in `dynamicList`).

Comment: @m0skit0 He adds a new "B" node after `list`, but `list` has never been added to `dynamicList`. the `insertAfter()` method only adds to the `Node` passed to it, not to any node already in the `DynamicList`.  He's created `list->"B"->bNode->aNode` on their own.  `dynamicList` only consists of `"C"->"A"`.

Comment: @azurefrog Yeah, just saw that, that's right, I think you can answer him.

Comment: @m0skit0 It's done.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is that you are creating several bare `Node` objects, which are not part of `dynamicList`, so your list is shorter than you think it is, and your print statements are running off the end.

Let's look at what your code is actually doing:

```
 Node aNode = new Node ("A", null);
 Node bNode = new Node ("B", aNode);
 Node list = new Node ("C", bNode);
```

This will create three `Node`s which are in a chain

```
list -> bNode -> aNode -> null
```

You then create a `DynamicList` and add a couple `String`s to it:

```
 DynamicList dynamicList = new DynamicList();   
 dynamicList.insertFirst("A");
 dynamicList.insertFirst("C");
```

You haven't shown the code for `insertFirst(String)` but we can safely assume it creates a new `Node` for each `String` you add, which leaves you with this:

```
(stand-alone)  list -> bNode -> aNode -> null
(dynamicList)  "C" -> "A" -> null
```

Now let's examine what happens when you `dynamicList.insertAfter(list, "B");`

First the method checks to see if the list is empty (which it isn't, since you've added "A" and "C" to it).  However, it then creates a new `Node` based on the `String` you give it and inserts it *after the parameter* `Node`.  Nowhere does it check to see if that `Node` actually exists in the `DynamicList`.

This means that you end up with this:

```
(stand-alone)  list -> "B" -> bNode -> aNode -> null
(dynamicList)  "C" -> "A" -> null
```

This is what is leading to the NPE when you try to print:

```
System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getInfo());
(dynamicList)  "C" -> "A" -> null
               ^^^                  prints "C"

System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getNext().getInfo());
(dynamicList)  "C" -> "A" -> null
                      ^^^           prints "A"

System.out.println(dynamicList.getList().getNext().getNext().getInfo());
(dynamicList)  "C" -> "A" -> null
                             ^^^    null has no info to get
```

### Solution

Instead of calling the insert method which takes a `String` and creates a new `Node`, you need to insert the `Node`s you've already created (assuming such methods exist):

```
 Node aNode = new Node ("A", null);
 Node list = new Node ("C", aNode);
 // creates list ("C") -> aNode ("A") -> null

 DynamicList dynamicList = new DynamicList();
 dynamicList.insertFirst(list);
 // dynamicList = list ("C") -> aNode ("A") -> null
 dynamicList.insertAfter(list, "B");
 // dynamicList = list ("C") -> "B" -> aNode ("A") -> null
```

An even simpler solution would be to never manually create any `Node` and just let the `DynamicList` do all the work:

```
 DynamicList dynamicList = new DynamicList();
 dynamicList.insertFirst("A");
 dynamicList.insertFirst("B");
 dynamicList.insertFirst("C");
 // dynamicList = "C" -> "B" -> "A" -> null
```

Comment: Hello azurefrog, thank you for your answer!  I tried the second solution you mentioned and it worked! I used "insertAfter" method because I want to make sure this method works too.

Comment: Hello azurefrog, I followed you suggestion to create an "insertMethod (Node x)." This method takes Nodes as parameters.   And this is what I have:                                                                    dynamicList.insertFirst(list);
      dynamicList.insertAfter(list,"A");
      dynamicList.insertAfter(list, "B");       It is working. Is it because now when I run 'insertAfter(list, "A") for instance, Java knows the Node "list" exists in the dynamicList, so list is relatable to the dynamicList?